# How can I create a script of stored procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a script in T-SQL (maybe create a stored procedure?) that when executed will execute a list of stored procedures.

I envision something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sproc_execute
AS
EXEC sp_CustomSproc 'param1' , 'param2'
GO
EXEC sp_CustomSproc 'paramA' , 'paramB'
GO
EXEC sp_CustomSproc 'paramX' , 'paramY'
GO
EXEC sp_CustomSproc 'param3' , 'param4'
GO
```

Each parameter returns different results from the same stored procedure and is absolutely needed. Running it looks like it works, but is it the RIGHT way to do it?

Comment: just remove the `GO`s

Comment: What would be the final output?

Comment: We have data in one table, the params determine the output from that table and then get added to a new table to get actioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write the procedure like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sproc_execute
AS
BEGIN

 EXEC sp_CustomSproc 'param1' , 'param2'
 EXEC sp_CustomSproc 'paramA' , 'paramB'
 EXEC sp_CustomSproc 'paramX' , 'paramY'
 EXEC sp_CustomSproc 'param3' , 'param4'

END
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can certainly call the same proc repeatedly, consider if it would not be better to rewrite the proc to use a table-valued parameter and then send in the parameters you want.  The choice may depend on how much this proc is currently being called by other processes. Clearly if this is already being used in many places, then this may not be practical. But if this is a new proc that has not yet made it to prod, then consider this method instead.  This way if you need to vary multiple parameters at some future time, you do not have to write a new proc to call it.

Comment: The SPROC is a temporary measure until we finish development on the new component. The SPROC was also written by someone far more knowledgeable than myself so I am partially at a loss to recreate a new one. It is only being used in one place however, but doesn't seem worth the time to completely rework since it will be replaced here in a few months. Customer just needs the product to work in the meantime. 

Thank you for your comment, I have a lot of learning still to do with SQL.